# How to disable Combobox by dynamic property which is present inside the datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

I am unable to disable the combobox which is present inside the WPF datagrid in mvvm.

I have tried to achieve this by setting the property IsHitTestVisible to "false" in viewmodel, but it is not working.

Here is my code in XAML :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ErrorDescriptionList}" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding TestResultsIsHitTestVisible}" Text="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True" 
                  Background="Transparent" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Description,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         </ComboBox>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Could you please look into it and help us in solving it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `IsHitTestVisible` use `IsEnabled`.

Comment: Thanks for your timely response, tried using that property as well. But binding property to IsEnabled dependency property didn't work

Comment: @MahendraRaoBandaru What is the type of TestResultsIsHitTestVisible ?

Comment: It is a Boolean variable

Comment: @MahendraRaoBandaru Then its not possible. Do one thing : Place another DataGrid with auto-generate true, and see the value present in this variable for the corresponding row.

Comment: @MahendraRaoBandaru DataGrid shows CheckBox for boolean fields.

Comment: Else, can we make datagrid disabled but having scrollbar scrollable?

Comment: Yes you can do that easily. But first answer my comment above.

Comment: @MahendraRaoBandaru try this,  IsHitTestVisible="{Binding TestResultsIsHitTestVisible,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"